# equation of the hyperplane orthogonal to the general line v

Tags: euclidean-geometry, orthonormal

Given a line **v** in $R^n$ from point *a* to point *b*, what is the general equation of the hyperplane that passes through *a* and is orthogonalto **v**?

Ideally I am looking for the general solution in arbitrary dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left \langle x,v \right \rangle = \left \langle a,v \right \rangle$$

where $\left \langle p,q \right \rangle$ denotes the inner product between the vectors $p$ and $q$